# If i code a function to create a key-value pair, what will the Object it belongs to be?

Tags: javascript, function, object, return-value, key-value

I'm new to coding and i'm just learning some JavaScript. I'm learning about using return versus console.log and how you can use return values in other functions. Anyway, I see that you can create  a key-value pair using a function and the return statement. They gave an example like this:

```
  function newObject(val) { 
        return {
            prop: val
        }
   }
   newObject(50);

   // output would be: {prop:50}
```

I am a bit confused at this because what is the object of this key-value pair? The way I learned about creating objects is you do:

```
 var newObject = {
      prop: 50
 }
```

so here this key-value pair would belong to the newObject object which was declared as a variable. In the function example that I first gave, is the object still newObject except instead of it being declared as a variable it is a function?

a bit confused, maybe im getting  ahead of myself. Unsure how this key-value pair that was made through a function would be assigned to an object.

Comment: Oh boy, you're in for a ride

Comment: I just started learning coding...this is a bit discouraging..

Comment: _"this key-value pair would belong to the newObject"_ nope. `newObject` is a variable that holds a reference to the object `{ prop: 50 }`. It doesn't belong to it.

Comment: thank you @phuzi , so the variable named newObject is not the object but just holding the actual object? Does this mean the actual object IS the key-value pair? If the key-value pairs were {speed: 50, color: 'red'}... and I wanted the key-value pair to belong to a certain character in a game..like newCharacter.color = 'red'; is the newCharacter not the object but  just a variable holding a group of key-value pairs? i'm sorry i'm so confused.

Comment: That's essentially correct. There are some differences between reference and value types but don't worry about that just yet. Also try not to think of them as key-value pairs and think of them as properties with a value just like a variable has a value.

Comment: @phuzi so although the var newObject is not the actual object, can it be considered the "name" of the object that holds a reference to the actual object properties and values?

Comment: It's more the name of the reference that refers to the object.

Comment: @phuzi , thank you so much! This makes sense to me. Appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is totally understandable, I am sure a lot of us had the same doubt in the begin,  and it's great that you're diving into these concepts in JavaScript.

I'm not very good in explain things, but let's clarify the difference between these two approaches of creating an object with a key-value pair.

1 - Think of this like baking a single cake and putting it straight into a box labeled "newObject". You decide the flavor (the properties) right then and there. Here's your recipe:

```
var newObject = {
    prop: 50
};
```

You've made a cake (an object) with chocolate chips (property prop with value 50) and put it in the "newObject" box.

#### Using a Function to Make an Object

Now, imagine you're setting up a cake-making machine. This machine is your function. Every time you use it, you can tell it what kind of cake to make. Here's how you set up the machine:

```
function newObject(val) { 
    return {
        prop: val
    };
}
```

This machine is special. You tell it, "Hey, make a cake with val amount of chocolate chips!" (val is like saying "you choose how many chips"). When you want a cake, you just tell the machine how many chips to add:

```
var result = newObject(50);
```

This is like saying, "Hey machine, make me a cake with 50 chocolate chips!" Now, "result" is your box with this freshly made cake.

Ok, it is little dumb my explanation but I use to use it with my son...

#### Here is the real difference:

Direct Assignment vs Function:

- **Direct Assignment:** You create an object and assign it directly to a variable.
- **Function:** You create a function that returns an object. The object is created when you call the function.

With the function approach, you can dynamically create objects with different properties based on the function's parameters, making your code more flexible and reusable.

Direct assignment is straightforward and useful when the object's properties are static or known in advance.

The function approach is more powerful when you need to create multiple objects with similar structure but different values, or when the object's structure might depend on some logic or calculation.

Examples:

Directly Assigning to a Variable (Manual Process):

```
var cake = {
    flavor: 'vanilla',
    sugarAmount: '100g',
    chocolateChips: '50g'
};
```

Using a Function to Create the Object:

```
function makeCake(flavor, sugar, chips) {
    return {
        flavor: flavor,
        sugarAmount: sugar,
        chocolateChips: chips
    };
}

var myCake = makeCake('vanilla', '100g', '50g');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! So essentially, both are creating objects but when you're assigning it to a variable its more of a manual process to create. 

I just want to clarify because i'm a bit confused on the terminology after reading some replies on here. So if I wanted to make a cake with a few properties, such as flavor, sugar amount, chocolate chip amount etc, all 3 of these properties together(with their value) would make up an object right? There would not be 3 objects here but one object with 3 properties? Do we refer to the object name as the name of the function/var?

Comment: Yes,  you're right! When you're creating an object, whether it's through assigning it to a variable directly or using a function, you're essentially building one single object that can have multiple properties.   I will add one more peace of code there, and maybe will be better to understand

Comment: That new addition of code was very helpful. Thanks for taking the time to help with this! I was very confused when someone commented that the variable such as: var cake = {}, in this example is not the actual object. In my head, cake is the name of the object, and I think that is correct but if we are being technical it is not the actual object but just the name in terms of organizing it in my head this would be the cake object. Hope i'm getting the point here. Thanks so much

Comment: I would not focus on the assignment so much. `var cake = makeCake(…)` still assigns the object to the `cake` variable, no difference to the object literal here

Answer (score 2):

An [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) is an independent entity. It doesn't need a name, or a variable to be stored in, it can exist on its own. The properties (key-value pairs) belong to the object itself.

In your examples, the objects are created by evaluation of the object literals `{ prop: val }` and `{ prop: 50 }` respectively. The result is a reference to the object, a handle that can be copied, shared and passed around by your program. It can be returned from the `newObject` function, or stored in the `newObject` variable. Notice that the same reference can be stored in multiple variables or in none. It also can be stored in properties of other objects, which is quite common, without ever being touched by a variable.

So when we speak of "the `newObject` object", this is slightly sloppy (but common and broadly understood) terminology. The phrase actually means "the object to which the reference stored in the `newObject` variable is pointing". This only applies to your second example. In the first example, one would say "the object returned by `newObject()`" (in case there's just one call to the function, otherwise it would be ambiguous).

Comment: thank you very much. So newObject is not the actual object but it is either storing the object as a variable or returning it as a function. If there are a set of properties & values and I want them to belong to a specific character, i'm assuming the variable name or function name is still how i distinguish or name the character (for organization purposes when reading the code)? 

In  my head the properties and values all combined together make up the object which is 'named' through a function or variable? sorry i'm trying to use simple english to understand this

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*I want them to belong to a specific character*". But yes, for organisational purposes one usually does name objects by introducing a variable for them. However, you need to distinguish these names (which are only valid in a given context) from the objects that exist at runtime - with the simplest example being the code being executed multiple times, where the same name refers to a different object during each run.

Comment: Also consider `console.log( ({ example: "value" }).example )`: here an object is created, and immediately a property is accessed on it and then logged. The object is never named - and when discussing the code, all I can say is "the object" :-)

Comment: sorry, i am taking a free online front-end dev course and they described setting up objects like creating a new video game character with certain properties/values assigned to that character (object), that is what I meant by creating properties/values that belong to a specific character. I think i'm too early in the course to understand that the names need to be distinguished from the objects that exist at runtime. But thank you for this, hopefully I will fully understand your comment soon

Comment: thank you, @bergi , just reading your second comment. That is very helpful, I was very confused, I thought objects needed to have a name always but thank you this was a perfect example to show that you can create an object without a name.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense as an analogy. Another example could be an army: `const army = [ {rank: 2}, {rank: 0}, {rank: 0} ]`. It's just a list of soldiers, without every soldier having an individual variable for themselves. I can access them by the index in their array, or loop the entire array.

Comment: Great example with the soldiers all being separate objects inside an array labeled under the const army (I hope my interpretation is accurate). Very helpful to see objects written in a different way than my notes.